# force redirect to https via htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect, http-redirect

I want to force redirect any visit to my site to https.
My htaccess rules are the following:

```
# rewrite address
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mytestsite\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mytestsite.eu/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://www.mytestsite.eu/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mytestsite\.eu$   [NC] 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.mytestsite.eu/  [L,R]
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite the first three lines like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```